# How can I monitor apache server with zabbix

Tags: zabbix

I'm trying to monitor an apache server installed on Ubuntu 14.04 server with zabbix, but does not have a template to do. I want to get metric of active members with currents.

Answer (score 0):

While it isn't clear what is "active members with currents", I assume that's not basic webserver availability, which you could monitor with Zabbix agent items like proc.num, net.tcp.service and the built-in webmonitoring.

To monitor Apache requests served and other statistics, this howto provides some ideas, as well as a script and a template you could start from: https://www.zabbix.org/wiki/Docs/howto/apache_monitoring_script